# Why does it take me two clicks to go the appropriate direction when moving through my images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a body whose background image changes when clicking on a div. Depending on whether it is the left or right div, the image changes in different directions.

However, I notice that it takes me two clicks to go the direction I want. For instance if I want to go from picture 1 to picture 2, the first click sends me to picture zero and then the second click to picture 1 and then 2 etc.

Could someone take a look at my JavaScript and see what might be causing this?

HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript/imageclick.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/imgCSS.css">
    </head>
    <body id="imgClickAndChange" style="margin: 0px; background: url('./Images/furnace2.png'); background-size: contain;">
    <div>
       <div id="div-left" style="height: 100%; width: 50%; float: left" onclick="changeImageMinus()">
       </div>
        <div id="div-right" style="height: 100%; width: 50%; float: right" onclick="changeImagePlus()">
       </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
var counter = 1;

function changeImageMinus(){
    console.log("minus");
    if(counter == 0){
        $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background", "url(./Images/furnace2.png)");
        $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background-size", "contain");
        counter = 5;
        console.log(counter);
    }
    else if(counter == 1){
       $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background", "url(./Images/furnace3.png)");
       $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background-size", "contain");
        counter--;
        console.log(counter);
    }
    else if(counter == 2){
        $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background", "url(./Images/furnace4.png)");
        $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background-size", "contain");
        counter--;
        console.log(counter);
    }
    else if(counter == 3){
        $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background", "url(./Images/furnace5.png)");
        $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background-size", "contain");
        counter--;
        console.log(counter);
    }
    else if(counter == 4){
        $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background", "url(./Images/furnace6.png)");
        $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background-size", "contain");
        counter--;
        console.log(counter);
    }
    else if(counter == 5){
        $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background", "url(./Images/furnace7.png)");
        $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background-size", "contain");
        counter--;
        console.log(counter);
    }
};

function changeImagePlus(){
    console.log("plus");
    if(counter == 0){
        $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background", "url(./Images/furnace2.png)");
        $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background-size", "contain");
        counter++;
        console.log(counter);
    }
    else if(counter == 1){
        $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background", "url(./Images/furnace3.png)");
        $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background-size", "contain");
        counter++;
        console.log(counter);
    }
    else if(counter == 2){
        $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background", "url(./Images/furnace4.png)");
        $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background-size", "contain");
        counter++;
        console.log(counter);
    }
    else if(counter == 3){
        $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background", "url(./Images/furnace5.png)");
        $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background-size", "contain");
        counter++;
        console.log(counter);
    }
    else if(counter == 4){
        $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background", "url(./Images/furnace6.png)");
        $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background-size", "contain");
        counter++;
        console.log(counter);
    }
    else if(counter == 5){
        $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background", "url(./Images/furnace7.png)");
        $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background-size", "contain");
        counter = 0;
        console.log(counter);
    }
};
```

Comment: Seems to work as expected for me http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jmOYeO goes 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 if you click the red box. goes 2, 3, 2, 7, 6 if you click the blue box.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seemed to work properly, however it is much more code than is necessary.

The following reduces your code dramatically. You only need one function here and you don't need a separate test for each value of `counter` since the new image is always 2 more than the current image.

Also, inline HTML event handlers (onclick, onmouseover, etc.) should not be used. Event handling should be done in JavaScript with `addEventListener`.

```js
// Get references to the DOM objects
var changeDown = document.getElementById("div-left");
var changeUp = document.getElementById("div-right");

// Set up the event handlers. Both elements will call the same handler, but 
// each will pass an argument indicating the direction to scroll the images.
changeDown.addEventListener("click", function(){
  changeImage("down");
});

changeUp.addEventListener("click", function(){
  changeImage("up");
});

var counter = 1;

// Just one function is needed here. The direction argument will determine 
// whether to go up or down
function changeImage(direction){

  // Since this was in every condition, just write it once:
  $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background-size", "contain");
    
  // All images use the same path, except for the number in the file name
  var fileName = "./Images/furnaceNUM.png";
    
  // If the counter is at an edge, don't go past it, otherwise adjust the counter
  // according to the direction
  if(counter == 0 && direction == "down"){
    counter = 5;
  } else if(counter == 5 && direction == "up"){
    counter = 0;
  } else if(direction == "down"){
    counter--;
  } else {
    counter++
  }
    
  // The displayed image will always be 2 more than the counter
  $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background", "url(" + fileName.replace("NUM", counter + 2) + ")");    
    
  // Since you want to log the counter all the time, just write it once
  console.log("direction: " + direction, ", counter: " + counter, ", Displayed image: " + fileName.replace("NUM", counter + 2));
};
```

```css
#div-left { background-color:rgba(255, 0,0,.2); }
#div-right { background-color:rgba(0, 255,0,.2); text-align:right;  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div-left" style="height: 100%; width: 50%; float: left">&lt;&lt;</div>
<div id="div-right" style="height: 100%; width: 50%; float: right">&gt;&gt;</div>
```

Comment: Aw, poor RP12 doesn't know what hit him/her ;) Instead of "up" and "down" might as well pass  +1 and -1 to changeImage() and add to counter, then offset out of range numbers. Maybe throw a modulus in the mix.

Comment: @yezzz All true, but I wanted to keep the logic tied to the original two functions to minimize the shock to RP12 when he/she saw my reformulated code.

Answer (score 0):

Because you set var counter at the end of each if statement, the next click will set the background in the direction you *last* clicked, instead of the direction you *just* clicked.

For example:

- On page load, background is furnace2.png and counter = 1
- On clicking #div-right, background will be furnace3.png (because counter = 1), and then changeImagePlus() sets counter = 2
- On clicking #div-left, background will be furnace4.png (because counter = 2), and then changeImageMinus() sets counter = 1

Instead, set counter to 0 initially and alter it *before* your if statements. Then it will behave like this:

- On page load, background is furnace2.png and counter = 0
- On clicking #div-right, changeImagePlus() sets counter = 1, and background will be furnace3.png
- On clicking #div-left, changeImageMinus() sets counter = 0, and background will be furnace2.png again

  ```
  counter = 0;
  function changeImageMinus() {
    if (counter == 0) {
      counter = 5;
    }
    else {
      counter--;
    }

    if (counter == 0) {
      $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background", "url(./Images/furnace2.png)");
    }
    // Etc.
  }
  ```